# Counting eligible minutes with hours as a group -python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the number of eligible minutes while having the hour as a group. As I am working with a large dataset, is it possible to use pandas aggregate function to have this output?

```
user minutes hour
1    778     12
1    779     12
1    780     13
1    781     13
1    782     13
1    783     13
```

I tried using `df.groupby('hour').count()` but the output is wrong.

```
user hour minutes
1    12   2
1    13   4
```

The correct output that I want is wrong as I want the 780th minute to be inclusive in hour 12 too.

```
user hour minutes
1    12   3
1    13   4
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`divmod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.divmod.html) to get the division and remainder by 60 and add missing rows with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
s1,s2 = df['minutes'].divmod(60)
(pd
 .concat([df,
          # select rows where hour is multiple of 60
          # and matching hour is not already the previous hour
                                          # decrement hour
          df[s1.ne(df['hour']-1)&s2.eq(0)].eval('hour = hour-1')
          ])
 .groupby('hour')
 .agg({'hour': 'first', 'minutes': 'count'})
)
```

Or, if you already know that hour and minutes match, simplify by using only the [`mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html):

```
mask = df['minutes'].mod(60).eq(0)
(pd
 .concat([df,
          df[mask].eval('hour = hour-1')
          ])
 .groupby('hour')
 .agg({'hour': 'first', 'minutes': 'count'})
)
```

output:

```
      hour  minutes
hour               
12      12        3
13      13        4
```